# Change nav link class and show selected div content on click (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to use JQuery to add/remove a nav link class as well as show the div content using the click event.

At the moment, I can do one or the other, but not both at the same time. When I add the on-click class I can no longer toggle the div content.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peggory/19wruzvx/2/) (not sure why it won't let me use the JS window so had to place it in the HTML sorry, again new to it...)

**Expected:**

Onclick changes the selected link to an active class, e.g.,

```
<li><a href="javascript:showStep('1');" >1</a></li>
```

To

```
<li><a class="active" href="javascript:showStep('1');" >1</a></li>
```

And shows changes the div style from:

```
<div class="toggleStep" id="1">Step 1 </div>
```

To

```
<div class="toggleStep" id="1" style="display: block;">Step 1 </div>
```

**Edit**: The solution below by Facundo Corradini is a nice fix, but I was hoping to get this running with JQuery. I have edited the question to focus it to JQuery and removed the CSS tag. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved**

I arrived at a solution by moving things around a bit. It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it does the task I wanted.

I can't mark this as resolved for 24-hours, but will do so.

Updated JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/peggory/19wruzvx/4/)

```
function showStep(selectedStep)
{
//global variables used for eaasy changes if needed
var showDelay = 200; //milliseconds
var hideDelay = 600; //milliseconds
//Create an array of Steps and cycle through them
$('.toggleStep').each(function(index)
{
    //Check if the step was selected
    if ($(this).attr("id") == selectedStep)
    {
        //Show the content
        $(this).show(showDelay);
        //Function to style the active step
        //Prepare the document to handle onClick events
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //handle onClick from the stepProgress class
            $('.stepProgress li a').click(function(e)
            {
                //Remove any active class
                $('.stepProgress li.active').removeClass('active');
                //Add the active class
                var $parent = $(this).parent();
                $parent.addClass('active');
                //Prevent default browser behaviour for urls
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        //Hide all other steps
        $(this).hide(hideDelay);
        $('#landing').hide(hideDelay);
    }
});
}
```

Also I found removing the `e.preventDefault();` fixed the issue:

```
//Function to style the active step
//Prepare the document to handle onClick events
$(document).ready(function()
{
//handle onClick from the stepProgress class
$('.stepProgress li a').click(function()
{
    //Remove any active class
    $('.stepProgress li.active').removeClass('active');
    //Add the active class
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.addClass('active');
});
})

//Function to show the selected step
function showStep(selectedStep)
{
//global variables used for eaasy changes if needed
var showDelay = 200; //milliseconds
var hideDelay = 600; //milliseconds
//Create an array of Steps and cycle through them
$('.toggleStep').each(function(index)
{
    //Check if the step was selected
    if ($(this).attr("id") == selectedStep)
    {
        //Show the selected content only
        $(this).show(showDelay);
    }
    else
    {
        //Hide all other steps
        $(this).hide(hideDelay);
        $('#landing').hide(hideDelay);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JQuery for that. Actually, you don't even need javascript for that. You can totally get away with using the :target CSS selector to switch the correct div display from none to whatever you need (probably block)

```
<nav>
  <ul class="stepProgress">
    <li><a href="#1" >1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2" >2</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<div id="1"> Step 1 </div>
<div id="2"> Step 2 </div>

div{
  width:200px; height:200px;
  border:2px solid grey;
  text-align:center;
  display:none;
}

div:target{
  display:block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/19wruzvx/3/